# .run files being read as text files 16.04

Tags: 16.04, files, xampp

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a former Windows 8.1 laptop (from a USB drive), and I am trying to install [XAMPP](http://apachefriends.org) on it. I put the .run file I downloaded on a SD card (I can't get wifi on the laptop) and moved it to my downloads folder. However, the system is showing it as a text file. I tried `sudo chmod +x xampp.run`, which worked (it became executable), but when I tried running it: `sudo xampp.run`, I got a lot of "question mark" icons. The system tried reading it out in the Terminal, instead of opening it. Why isn't this working? It worked on both previous versions I've used (14.04 and 15.10).

Comment: The problem was the SD card. For some reason, it's making the run files text files. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod +x xampp.run` will grant the file executable permission.

Then `./xampp.run` will execute the `.run` file.

You have entered `sudo xampp.run` into the terminal without the `./`, which does nothing usually.

Hope it helps

Comment: You got the answer reward by five minutes :)

Comment: well i am glad your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

After giving them file executable permission run files by adding `./` at the start.
Make it a rule of thumb.
When you don't give `./` the programs in your $PATH directory are executed.

Adding `./` says to the terminal something like "Search in this directory and nowhere else".

Hope this helps.